# Accessing Parameters in Functions Using Eval and List Comprehension (Python)

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Why does this not work?

```
f = lambda A, B:[eval(i) for i in 'AB']
```

In Python 3, the following error is returned:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 1, in <module>
  File "python", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "python", line 1, in <listcomp>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'A' is not defined
```

when trying `f(1, 2)`. However, surely the function should return `[1, 2]`...

Comment: what is the purpose of such function? what is the benefit of using `eval` in such simple code?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest It's actually for code golf. My actual function is a lot more complicated; I simplified it a lot to make this question clearer. Do you know why it doesn't work?

Comment: 'AB' is just a string consisting of the letter 'A' and 'B'. It has nothing to do with the variables A and B passed to your lambda function. Moreover, eval() applied to integers will lead to TypeError.

Comment: @limes Surely eval('A') would return the value of the parameter A...

Comment: @J843136028: yes, but here you define 'AB'. Where is the variable named AB? You cannot just concatenate two variables into one string.

Comment: @limes So would it work if I did ['A', 'B'] instead?

Comment: `f = lambda A, B:[eval(i) for i in ['A','B']]` `f(1,2)` `NameError: name 'A' is not defined`. No.

Comment: @limes I still don't understand why...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: How can I run eval() in the local scope of a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36616739/python-how-can-i-run-eval-in-the-local-scope-of-a-function)

Comment: Basically, I think what's going on here is the list comp has its own scope - whatever bindings it needs from the enclosing scope are just made when the comp is created and that's it. But you are trying to resolve, with eval, while the scope is running. There is no binding for these function local vars though so it poops out. It's also a perfectly reasonable (if esoteric) question, not sure why everyone is yelling at you.

Comment: @pvg Thanks for the detailed, helpful explanation.