# what's the name of a nested function ? why doesn't eval see the nested function?

Tags: python, scope, namespaces, eval

I get the below error when I try to run this code. I'm trying to initialize a list with function pointers. It appears the eval doesn't see the functions. I'm guessing there's some kind of scoping going on that I don't understand. It works when I create the table by hand as you can see. I'm trying to avoid having to maintain a list of functions. This also worked when I made the functions global.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/westgate/code/python/try/x.py", line 27, in <module>
     main()
   File "/home/westgate/code/python/try/x.py", line 23, in main
     fxns_eval = [eval(fxn_name) for fxn_name in dir() if fxn_name.startswith('fxn_')]
   File "/home/westgate/code/python/try/x.py", line 23, in <listcomp>
     fxns_eval = [eval(fxn_name) for fxn_name in dir() if fxn_name.startswith('fxn_')]
   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
 NameError: name 'fxn_bar' is not defined
```

---

```
import inspect

def main():

    def fxn_foo():
        print('in foo '+inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_name)

    def fxn_bar():
        print('in bar '+inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_name)

    for i in dir():
        if i.startswith('fxn_'):
            print(i)

    fxn_bar()

    fxns = [ fxn_foo, fxn_bar ]

    fxns[1]()

    fxns_eval = [eval(fxn_name) for fxn_name in dir() if fxn_name.startswith('fxn_')]

    fxns_eval[1]()

main()
```

Comment: Your functions are defined within `main()` so they are local. Put them out and they will be global.

Comment: I don't want them to be global. is there a way to make it work as nested functions?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/36617153/719547

Comment: Yes: put them in a list or a tuple and iterate through it instead of `dir()`

Comment: This is because list comprehensions essentially create a function scope, note, `eval('fxn_bar')` outside the comprehension works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are not passing `locals` explicitly, so . From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval):

> If both dictionaries are omitted, the expression is executed in the
>   environment where eval() is called.

However, the environment is the list comprehension, which creates it's own scope, and neither of those functions are in the list-comprehension's local namespace, nor in the global namespace. You want *`main`'s local namespace* So note, this works:

```
>>> def main():
...    def foo(): 'foo'
...    print(eval('foo'))
...
>>> main()
<function main.<locals>.foo at 0x10c3ba6a8>
```

Pass `globals` and `locals()` explicitly! **But** you have to use them as free variables to the list-comprehension's scope, since it is essentially like another nested function scope, you can't just do this either:

```
>>> def main():
...    def foo(): 'foo'
...    def bar(): 'bar'
...    print([eval(x, globals(), locals()) for x in dir()])
...
>>> main()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in main
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <listcomp>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'bar' is not defined
```

Indeed, that is equivalent to *not passing the arguments at all*.

You could do:

```
>>> def main():
...    def foo(): 'foo'
...    def bar(): 'bar'
...    locs, globs = locals(), globals()
...    print([eval(x, globs, locs) for x in dir()])
...
>>> main()
[<function main.<locals>.bar at 0x10bded1e0>, <function main.<locals>.foo at 0x10c3ba6a8>, {'__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__package__': None, '__loader__': <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>, '__spec__': None, '__annotations__': {}, '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>, 'n1': 1014.308, 'n0': 961.06, 'p1': 18.59, 'p0': 19.65, 'q1': 1014.308, 'q0': 961.06, 'main': <function main at 0x10c3ba620>}, {'foo': <function main.<locals>.foo at 0x10c3ba6a8>, 'bar': <function main.<locals>.bar at 0x10bded1e0>, 'globs': {'__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__package__': None, '__loader__': <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>, '__spec__': None, '__annotations__': {}, '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>, 'n1': 1014.308, 'n0': 961.06, 'p1': 18.59, 'p0': 19.65, 'q1': 1014.308, 'q0': 961.06, 'main': <function main at 0x10c3ba620>}, 'locs': {...}}]
>>>
```