# Python lambda and eval scoping within function

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, eval

I have the following code

```
def foo(q, s):
    a = 1
    f = lambda x : eval(s)
    return f(1)

foo(1, "x+a+q")
```

I would expect the function call to return `3`, however I get a `NameError` instead. I assume that's because `eval` doesn't have access to the local scope. However I wasn't able to make it work even after passing `locals()` or a dictionary with the objects.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36616739/python-how-can-i-run-eval-in-the-local-scope-of-a-function

Comment: Another interesting discussion on scoping rules related to `eval` and `lambda`: https://bugs.python.org/issue1153622

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, this is clearly documented:

> Note, `eval()` does not have access to the [nested
> scopes](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-nested-scope)
> (non-locals) in the enclosing environment.

So, you have the local scope of `f` and the nonlocal scope of `foo`, which `eval` will not have access to. You will have to capture the non-local scope and force `eval` to use it. How exactly you make this work is up to you and your use-case, here is one example:

```
>>> def foo(q, s):
...     a = 1
...     nonlocals = locals()
...     def f(x):
...         return eval(s, {**locals(), **nonlocals})
...     return f(1)
...
>>> foo(1, "x+a+q")
3
```

Some things to note:

1. I used the `locals()` of the function `f` first. You could switch the order if you want, and it won't matter **if and only if** there would be no name collisions. Otherwise it is up to you which takes precedence
2. In the more recent versions of Python, `{**locals(), **nonlocals}` could be `locals() | nonlocals`
3. I didn't use a lambda expression here, to comport with PEP8 style guidelines. Don't assign the result of a `lambda` expression to a name, that defeats *the entire purpose* of lambda expressions, which are to be anonymous.
4. You should consider whether you really need to use `eval` here. It is likely not the best solution to your problem.

Comment: thank you! I don't really like `eval` either, though I need to read a function definition from an Excel cell using `xlwings` so didn't really see another way